# Define the URL of an Dataobject - Silverstripe 3.1

Tags: php, silverstripe

How can I change the url of an dataobject?
I can get the dataobject under the following url with this function.

**www.domain.tld/articles/art?=1234**

```
    public function ArticleByID() {
    $articleID = isset($_GET['art']) ? $_GET['art'] : false;
    return $articleID ? Articles::get()->filter(array('ShortNumber' => $articleID))->First() : false;
}
```

But what I want is for example this
**www.domain.tld/articles/1234** or **www.domain.tld/members/member-name**

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `show()` function that you would call on your `ArticleHolder` to get and return the `Articles` page you want with a URL like **www.domain.tld/articles/show/1234**

**ArticleHolder.php**

```php
...

class ArticleHolder_Controller extends Page_Controller {

    ...

    public function show(SS_HTTPRequest $request) {

        if ($request->param('ID') && $article = Articles::get()->filter(array('ShortNumber' => $page->param('ID')))->First()) {

            return $this->customise(array(
                'Title' => $article->Title,
                'Content' => $article->Content,
                'MetaTitle' => $article->MetaTitle,
                'MetaDescription' => $article->MetaDescription,
                'MetaKeywords' => $article->MetaKeywords
            ))->renderWith(
                array('ArticlesPage', 'Page')
            );
        }

        return $this->httpError(404);
    }

    ...

}
```

Or, better yet, use `URLSegment` to get your articles. For this you need to the `URLSegment` in your `Article` class.

There is an excellent tutorial for this at ssbits.com: 
http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-2-using-model-admin-and-url-segments-to-create-a-product-catalogue/

The tutorial is for Silverstripe 2.4, but the code should work with minor tweaks in Silverstripe 3.1.

There is also a module based off this tutorial called DataObjectAsPage: https://github.com/arambalakjian/DataObjects-as-Pages

You could use this a base for your code.

Comment: Hi 3dgoo, I tried this tutorial. This was a good tip! :) But I've got some problems with it. Perhaps you can help me. I made a new question for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19560804/dataobjects-as-pages-ssbits-tutorial-sivlerstripe-3