# display titles from many_many relation in GridField - Silverstripe

Tags: silverstripe

How can I display the titles from a many_many relation in a GridField Summary?

I tried it with RelationName.Title but the result was only an empty field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**colymba**'s answer already said most of it, but in addition you can also specify a method in `$summary_fields`. This allows you to display image thumbnails in a GridField or as you need it, piece together your own string from the titles of a many_many relation.

```
class TeamMember extends DataObject {
    private static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Text',
        'Birthday' => 'Date',
    );
    private static $has_one = array(
        'Photo' => 'Image'
    );
    private static $has_many = array(
        'Teams' => 'Team'
    );
    private static $summary_fields = array(
        'PhotoThumbnail',
        'Title',
        'Birthday',
        'TeamsAsString',
    );
    public function getPhotoThumbnail() {
        // display a thumbnail of the Image from the has_one relation
        return $this->Photo() ? $this->Photo()->CroppedImage(50,50) : '';
    }
    public function getTeamsAsString() {
        if (!$this->Teams()) {
           return 'not in any Team'; 
        }
        return implode(', ', $this->Teams()->Column('Title'));
        // or if one field is not enough for you, you can use a foreach loop:
        // $teamsArray= array();
        // foreach ($this->Teams() as $team) {
        //     $teamsArray[] = "{$team->ID} {$team->Title}";
        // }
        // return implode(', ', $teamsArray);
    }
}
```

alternative you can, as **colymba** pointed out, also use `setDisplayFields` to use different fields on different grids

Comment: Exactly what I needed and more - The thumbnail function was also very useful. Thank you

Comment: Is it also possible to get the Links for each team displayed in the Template? So that I can make links next to each player to the teams he is in. I tried it with modifying your function (the part in the comments) but without success

Comment: you mean in the cloumn where you have the team list like this: "Team 1, Team 2, Team 3" and when I press on "Team 3" I get to an edit form of that team? I guess its possible, but it might be a lot more complex, I would need to look into that

Comment: no, not in the GridField. Only for the frontend template. Is that easier?

Comment: yes it is. it is basically the same thing as on this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477858/define-the-url-of-an-dataobject-silverstripe-3-1

Answer (score 2):

there should be a couple solutions:

defining `$summary_fields` on the DataObject that is linked:

```
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'YourFieldName',
    'AnotherField'
);
```

or with the `GridFieldConfig` on the Page/DataObject that defines the relation:

```
$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(      
    'FieldName' => 'GridFieldColumnName',
    'AnotherFieldName' => 'AnotherGridFieldColumnName',
));
```

`$config` being your `GridFieldConfig` instance used by `GridField`.

**EDIT**

for more advanced formatting/control over the data included in the GridField, you can use `setFieldFormatting`:

```
$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setDisplayFields(array(      
    'TeamLink' => 'Edit teams'
));

$config->getComponentByType('GridFieldDataColumns')->setFieldFormatting(array(
    'TeamLink' => function($value, $item)
    {
      // $item here would be a TeamMember instance
      // since the GridField displays TeamMembers

      $links = 'No teams';

      $teamModelAdminClass = 'TeamModelAdmin'; //change to your classname
      $teams = $item->Teams(); // get the teams

      if ( $teams->count() > 0 )
      {
        $links = '';
        $teamClass = $teams->dataClass;

          $teamAdminURL = Config::inst()->get($teamModelAdminClass, 'url_segment');
          $teamEditAdminURL = 'admin/'.$teamAdminURL.'/'.$teamClass.'/EditForm/field/'.$teamClass.'/item/';       

          foreach($teams as $team)
          {
            $links .= '<a href="'.$teamEditAdminURL.$team->ID.'/edit">Edit '.$team->Title.'</a><br/>';
          }
      }

      return $links;
    }
));
```

Here `setFieldFormatting` will output edit links to all teams that a TeamMember is part of in a `TeamLink` column defined by `setDisplayFields` (might not be the best example, but hope you get the idea, although not tested).

Comment: hi, thank you but defining summary_fields wasn't the problem. each member has multiple teams, and i needed to shwo a list of the teams the member is in. But your second code snippet was usefull :) thank your for that

Comment: no worries... if you want some more control over the data displayed in the GridField, you can use `setFieldFormatting`, see the edit in the answer.

Comment: nice. but until now i don't know where to use it. have you got an example for what i can use it?

Comment: updated the answer with a more in depth example... you'll probably have to adapt with your own code though.