# DataObjects as Pages (SSBits Tutorial) - Sivlerstripe 3

Tags: php, silverstripe

I tried to use this tutorial http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-2-using-model-admin-and-url-segments-to-create-a-product-catalogue/ from ssbits for my news section.

I think I did everything right. But I can't save the NewsObject. This error appears

> Notice at line 155 of /mysite/code/DataObjects/NewsObject.php

Line 155 is this

```
$this->URLSegment = SiteTree::generateURLSegment($this->Title);
```

But what's wrong here?

Here's my whole code. Perhaps someone can help me to solve this problem.

NewsObject: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5278c59fd7904

NewsCategory: http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5268d844c9ee2

Comment: this looks quite vague and poorly researched.... Is there more than 'Notice....' in the error. Also that tutorial was for SS 2.4.* it will required some updating for SS 3...

Comment: No that's the only error (dev mode is on). I went through the tutorial step by step and updated things like static... to private static, function to public function etc. I think the rest should be ok for ss3?

Answer (score 1):

This is how the [DataObjects-as-Pages](https://github.com/arambalakjian/DataObjects-as-Pages/blob/master/code/DataObjects/DataObjectAsPage.php) module does it:

```php
$this->URLSegment = $this->generateURLSegment($this->Title);
```

This uses a custom function in the same class:

```php
public function generateURLSegment($title)
{
    $filter = URLSegmentFilter::create();
    $t = $filter->filter($title);

    // Fallback to generic page name if path is empty (= no valid, convertable characters)
    if(!$t || $t == '-' || $t == '-1') $t = "page-$this->ID";

    // Hook for extensions
    $this->extend('updateURLSegment', $t, $title);

    return $t;
}
```

Comment: sry but i absolutely don't get it. I'm confused with which code i need and which not.

Comment: Add the `generateURLSegment` function to your NewsObject class. Then replace your line `$this->URLSegment = SiteTree::generateURLSegment($this->Title);` with `$this->URLSegment = $this->generateURLSegment($this->Title);`.

Comment: that was what i tried first, but it results in an `Error at line 847 of /framework/control/injector/Injector.php` after saving the data object. Also the update url Button doesn't work. after clicking it, the standard 'new-product' is still in the field

Comment: I haven't had any time to look into this for you. When I do, I will and I'll let you know.

Comment: Prehaps you can give me a small hint, so i can try to figure out why it's not working.

Comment: I don't know what could be wrong without looking at the code, so I can't give any hints. The best I can do is point you to some code that does this an works:
https://github.com/arambalakjian/DataObjects-as-Pages/blob/master/code/DataObjects/DataObjectAsPage.php

Comment: I'll try it. I hope you got time soon.

Comment: I'm still stuck and I absolutely don't know what to do. Thats my last try to get help for this. Perhaps @3dgoo has time for this or someone else knows how to fix it.